# many to many with self referencing how to correct join

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have Category entity with many to many self referencing, and I want build simple query for selection all main categories, for that in raw query I just one time ineer joing table with many to many FK and add simple condition `csc.category_id = c0_ .id`. But I'm not undertand how to do it with query builder. I don't want use native query because I need Entity object classes and I don't want spent time for result set logic and I think doctrine should have exist solution, I just not found it

```
class Category

/**
 * Many Users have many Users.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="subCategories", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\Cache("NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 */
private $mainCategory;

/**
 * @var CategoryConfigurations
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CategoryConfigurations", mappedBy="categoryId", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\Cache("NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE")
 */
private $categoryConfigurations;
```

my native query which return correct result 15 row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c0_.id AS id_0

FROM category c0_ 
INNER JOIN category_sub_categories AS csc ON csc.category_id = c0_ .id
WHERE c0_.custome_category = 't'
```

And my query builder example

```
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('
            c
        ')
        ->innerJoin('c.mainCategory', 'm')
        ->where('m.id = c.id')
    ;
```

which return

```
SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.category_name AS category_name_1, c0_.custome_category AS custome_category_2, c0_.created_at AS created_at_3, c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_4 


FROM category c0_ 

INNER JOIN category_sub_categories c2_ ON c0_.id = c2_.sub_category_id 
INNER JOIN category c1_ ON c1_.id = c2_.category_id 

WHERE c1_.id = c0_.id
```

regarding this query I had zero instead 15 row. How to correct building query builder or DQL ?

Comment: The `where` is wrong. In fact I don't think you even need it. Try removing it and see if it's the correct result.

Comment: Are you sure, that it's a many-to-many? since the field is called `mainCategory` I would assume that field to be many-to-one and the related field `subCategories` (which you omitted from your code sample) would be one-to-many. can a category have more than one mainCategory? if so, it should be called `mainCategories`. otherwise, it would also simplify your schema ... but you could also keep the join table, I presume. (via adding an explicit @ORM\JoinTable: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#jointable)

Comment: I reolved if, create separate entity, and when I join separate entityt I'm not faced with problem